# Are there any viable DNS or LDAP alternatives for distributed key/value storage and retrieval?

Tags: domain-name-system, ldap

I'm working on a software app that needs distributed decentralized name resolution, and isn't bound to TCP/IP.  Or more precisely, I need to store a "key" and look up it's value, and the key may be a string, a number, or any other realistic data type.

Examples:

1. With a phone number, look up a name.  (or with an area code, redirect to the server that handles that exchange)
2. With an IP Address get a DNS name, or a Whois contact  (string value)
3. With a string, get an IP,  ( like a DNS TXT or SRV record).

I'm thinking out of the box here and looking for any software that allows for this.   (more info below)

- Are there any secure, scalable DNS alternatives that have gained notoriety?

I could ask on StackOverflow, but think the infrastructure groups would have better insight on this.

Edit More info:

I'm looking at "Namecoin" the DNS version of Bitcoin, and since that project is faltering, I'm looking at alternative ways to store name-value pairs, with an optional qualifier.

I think a name value pair is of global interest is useful, but on a limited scale.  Namecoin tried to be too much, and ended up becoming nothing.  I'm trying to solve that problem in researching alternatives and applying distributed technologies where applicable.

Bitcoin/Namecoin offers a Distributed Hash Table, which has some positive aspects, but not useful for DNS, except for root servers.

Comment: We need to know a *lot* more. What does your application do? You're looking for some name service that will only be used within your application - ie, by the servers it runs on, instead of by consumers of this service? Why not TCP - or in other words, what are you using instead of TCP? I think that might direct the answers quite strongly - I don't imagine that there's going to be a lot of options for a given protocol.

Comment: You need to expound on your issue without keeping this a "shopping question".  Your 2nd sentence tends to make it a shopping question.

Comment: @mfinni added more info... LMK

Comment: @Thecleaner I'm not "shopping" but trying to identify technologies or approaches that apply to storing a distributed name value pair.  LDAP might be an example, but is it more "secure"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question fully. You want DNS, but without TCP/IP? What's wrong with DNS for your purpose?

Comment: Can every node write? Can they write to any value, or only "their" values? How long can you wait for coherency, if at all?

Comment: I get you after your edits, just making sure.  Making it distributed and decentralized is obviously the hardest part otherwise any simple table app would do, I'd presume.  Maybe something like NoSQL?

Comment: @GomoX - he may not be storing IP information...I think he's just looking for something that stores name-value pairs of data that isn't conducive to using DNS.

Comment: Is LDAP "more secure" than what? DNS? That's a tough question to answer because it's almost hypothetical. LDAP is a protocol, not a product. And it's not automatically distributed, so I don't know that it solves the problem you're trying to solve but haven't really defined. Secure from what? Put either over IPSec and they're pretty damn secure.

Comment: @TheCleaner indeed, not clear at all. We need more information.

Comment: @TheCleaner  Distributing encrypted data is easy, determining who to trust without an arbiter is the tricky part.

Comment: @JamesRyan - there ya go...precisely right.

Comment: Edited my answer, and voting to move to SO.

Answer (score 2):

Any database would do this. LDAP is one such. any generic RDBMS is another. DNS and TXT records would do this.

Secure - from what? Snooping and impersonation? Use IPSec.

Distributed - here's where you need to define your terms. You can "distribute" the storage layer for a lot of these options above. Do you need instant or eventual consistency? Do certain updates need to be propagated faster than others? You can look at how MS handled multi-master replication in AD to see some of the ways these can be handled. If you need guaranteed consistency at all times, you probably need a single master that can confirm all writes.

You're not really giving us much more than hypotheticals to work with - you haven't defined what entities store the information, what entities write the information, and which one read it, nor how they do this, especially if it's not over TCP/IP.

I think you're asking too many questions in one package and not defining any or most of them well enough for us to answer.

Edit - I'm voting to move to SO, because you're asking for a type of tool that isn't usually in a systems-administrator's arsenal. I did some searching on "distributed JSON" and found a bunch of things like these:

http://www.rethinkdb.com/

https://code.google.com/p/persevere-framework/

If you're not using something that can speak JSON, then I'm sure you can find a similar project for whatever language you're working in, or a JSON library for it.

But again, this seems like a programming and design issue, if something like DNS can't fit the bill.